# VB.net Date Format Gridview dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, date, format

Hello
I'm trying to update a ms access database. I've got a gridview with a date that i use:

```
Dim tBox As TextBox = CType(gridStaff.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("sDate"), TextBox)
```

I then want to take the value from this textbox and assign it to a date variable.

```
Dim test As Date = CDate(tBox.Text)
```

The problem I have is that now when I put test variable into my sql update query it stores the date in this format. mm/dd/yyyy instead of the dd/mm/yyyy format I want.

Ive tried different ways to format it I read online but to no success yet. Any advice would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem the conversion from tBox.Text to Date, or is it at the sql update query level? -- You should probably give the sql statement a parameter with a strict type. Converting from tBox.Text into test should probably be done in a Culture aware manner:

'String to convert and target date:
  Dim dateString As String = "02/15/2011"
  Dim d As Date

' Specify English/US culture when converting string:
  Dim cul As Globalization.CultureInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
  d = Date.Parse(dateString, cul)

You could also rely on the default culture and simply let Date.Parse do the job without specifying the culture.

Comment: So close yet so far :(  It works to a point but If i went to change the date in the textbox the date is back in US format instead of UK.

Comment: if I try enter 16-5-2011 into the textbox I get this error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: I see your point, but the problem is that the parser needs to known the date format in advance. You could also choose to avoid the textbox and go for a calendar control instead. (Or use any other kind of date-ware control, where you are not dependent on a string format at all.)

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
Dim test As Date =  DateTime.ParseExact(tBox.Text, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or if your System is set up right and CultureInfo.CurrentCulture has the right date format,

```
Dim test As Date =  DateTime.Parse(tBox.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture )
```

instead of `CDate()`

Comment: Hi Bala R.
I tried what you suggested but I am getting this error.
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: @Bitzal, I had missed the ending quotes for the date format. I have fixed it now. can you try it?

Comment: @Bala R - I noticed that and made the fix myself - still had that error though :(

Comment: its just a date that is entered through a textbox. So it could be any date but in that format. Either way I crash out with the String was not recognized as valid datetime error.

Comment: @Bala R   Dim tBox As TextBox = CType(gridStaff.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("sDate"), TextBox)
        Dim test As Date = Date.ParseExact(tBox.Text, "d/m/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

That is the code im using - still getting String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.